# PHP - PayPal RESTful API SDK

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

I'm working on allowing PayPal Direct Credit Card payments in my website.  I have downloaded the PayPal PHP RESTful SDK from here https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/releases and I am following instructions on setting up the direct credit card payment from here...https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_creditcard/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox.

I'm stumped.  The SDK has a folder structure like the following:

```
composer->subfolders...
paypal->subfolders...
psr->subfolders...
autoload.php
```

So I include the autoload.php file in my PHP script, and when I try to perform the first step in the tutorial which is the following bit of code

```
$paypal = new OAuthTokenCredential($clientId, $clientSecret, $sdkConfig);
```

I get `Fatal error: Class 'OAuthTokenCredential' not found`

However, If I instead use the following code...

```
$paypal = new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential($clientId, $clientSecret, $sdkConfig);
```

I get a an object back which looks like the following:

```
PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential Object
(
    [clientId:PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential:private] => CLIENT_ID
    [clientSecret:PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential:private] => CLIENT_SECRET
    [accessToken:PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential:private] => 
    [tokenExpiresIn:PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential:private] => 
    [tokenCreateTime:PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential:private] => 
    [cipher:PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential:private] => PayPal\Security\Cipher Object
        (
            [secretKey:PayPal\Security\Cipher:private] => CLIENT_SECRET
        )

    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

But the `accessToken` which is what I need for Step 2 in the tutorial is empty.
What the heck am i doing wrong?  Can anyone give a straight forward step by step guide for this?  Is there one available that I'm not finding?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you linked to says it is for PHP, but it really isn't. [This one on PayPal's PHP SDK github is more directly for PHP.](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call) 
Here is the code from that page in case it goes away:

```
<?php
// 1. Autoload the SDK Package. This will include all the files
// and classes to your autoloader
// Used for composer based installation
require __DIR__  . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Use below for direct download installation
// require __DIR__  . '/PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php';

$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
  new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
    'AYSq3RDGsmBLJE-otTkBtM-jBRd1TCQwFf9RGfwddNXWz0uFU9ztymylOhRS',     // ClientID
    'EGnHDxD_qRPdaLdZz8iCr8N7_MzF-YHPTkjs6NKYQvQSBngp4PTTVWkPZRbL'      // ClientSecret
  )
);

// Save Credit Card to vault and then read it back
$creditCard = new \PayPal\Api\CreditCard();
$creditCard->setType("visa")
  ->setNumber("4417119669820331")
  ->setExpireMonth("11")
  ->setExpireYear("2019")
  ->setCvv2("012")
  ->setFirstName("Joe")
  ->setLastName("Shopper");

try {
  $creditCard->create($apiContext);
  echo $creditCard;
}
catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
  // This will print the detailed information on the exception. 
  //REALLY HELPFUL FOR DEBUGGING
  echo $ex->getData();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code.  I have updated to use it, however I still get back no value in the $apiContext object for accessToken, tokenExpiresIn and tokenCreateTime.  Also, the $creditCard->create($apiContext) call is failing with an error stating error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: It looks like the error I'm getting is due to the TLS 1.2 requirement.  I'm on PHP 5.4.7 - upgrading to 5.6 to see if that fixes the issue.  Thank you!

Comment: Ah yeah that sounds like the issue. Glad to help.